# N1ql query couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have scenario to insert a new attribute in couchbase document.

For ex : I have a document like:
{
 "x" : "value1",
 "y" : "value2"
}

I just want to insert another key "z", for which value should be taken from key "y".

My expected result should be like:
{
 "x" : "value1",
 "y" : "value2",
 "z" : "value2"
}

Note : "x" is unique id.

Kindly suggest me couchbase N1QL query for better performance.

Comment: Can you let us know what you have already tried and clarify what you mean by "better performance"?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update all documents

UPDATE default SET z = y;

If you need to update based on condition.

UPDATE default SET z = y WHERE x = "value1";